# Factoid question-answer pairs based on tables

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for a data set that contains factoid question-answer pairs based on tables.

Example:

- Table: [image]
- Question: what is the capital of Egypt?
- Answer: Cairo

Tables could be HTML, PDF or latex. I am most interested in table-question-answer written in English.

Comment: Kaggle held competitions for answering questions given multiple choices.  The domain was mostly science, chemistry, biology and the like.  You could take their data and simply use the question + the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[AI2 TabMCQ: Multiple Choice Questions aligned with the Aristo Tablestore](http://allenai.org/data.html)
:

> AI2 & Carnegie Mellon University (Sujay Kumar Jauhar)
>   This package contains a copy of the Aristo Tablestore (Nov. 2015 Snapshot), plus a large set of crowd-sourced multiple-choice questions covering the facts in the tables. Through the setup of the crowd-sourced annotation task, the package also contains implicit alignment information between questions and tables. For further information, see "TabMCQ: A Dataset of General Knowledge Tables and Multiple-choice Questions" (PDF included in this package).